# How to suppress parquet log messages in Spark?

Tags: logging, apache-spark, parquet

How to stop such messages from coming on my spark-shell console.

```
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: RecordReader initialized will read a total of 89213 records.
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 2 ms. row count = 120141
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 2 ms. row count = 89213
5 May, 2015 5:14:30 PM WARNING: parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutp
[Stage 12:=================================================>    (184 + 4) / 200]
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean ALL the messages coming from parquet or just the INFO ones (which seem to be the majority)?

Comment: @Panto All except error.

Comment: Can you change the log level in conf/log4j.properties and see what happened?

Comment: @YijieShen I still get the messages. Seems like it is not controlled from there.

Comment: I would try it myself and let you know when success.

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: @Panto 1.4.0 SNAPSHOT, built from source taken from github. I have tried the same on 1.3.0.

Comment: parquet Logging is a big issue still two years later with Spark 2.1.X.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from [SPARK-8118 issue comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8118?focusedCommentId=15045325&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15045325) seem to work:

> You can disable the chatty output by creating a properties file with these contents:

```
org.apache.parquet.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
```

> And then passing the path of the file to Spark when the application is
>   submitted. Assuming the file lives in /tmp/parquet.logging.properties
>   (of course, that needs to be available on all worker nodes):

```
spark-submit \
     --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/parquet.logging.properties" \`
      --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/parquet.logging.properties" \
      ...
```

Credits go to [Justin Bailey](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=m4dc4p).

Comment: This worked for me after I added the line org.apache.parquet.hadoop.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
to the properties file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this regressed --there are some large merges/changes they are making to the parquet integration...https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4412

Comment: Thanks for reopening the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for Spark 2.0. Edit file spark/log4j.properties and add:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool=ERROR
```

The lines for FileScanRDD and CodecPool will help with a couple of logs that are very verbose as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was WRT Spark, but I recently had this issue when using Parquet with Hive in CDH 5.x and found a work-around. Details are here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4412?focusedCommentId=16118403

Contents of my comment from that JIRA ticket below:

> This is also an issue in the version of parquet distributed in CDH
>   5.x. In this case, I am using `parquet-1.5.0-cdh5.8.4` (sources available here: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5)
>
> However, I've found a work-around for mapreduce jobs submitted via
>   Hive. I'm sure this can be adapted for use with Spark as well.
>
> - Add the following properties to your job's configuration (in my case, I added them to `hive-site.xml` since adding them to
>     `mapred-site.xml` didn't work:
>
> ```
> <property>
>   <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
>   <value>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=parquet-logging.properties</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
>   <value>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=parquet-logging.properties</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>mapreduce.child.java.opts</name>
>   <value>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=parquet-logging.properties</value>
> </property>
> ```
>
> - Create a file named `parquet-logging.properties` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> # Note: I'm certain not every line here is necessary. I just added them to cover all possible
> # class/facility names.you will want to tailor this as per your needs.
> .level=WARNING
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=WARNING
>
> parquet.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> parquet.hadoop.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> org.apache.parquet.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> org.apache.parquet.hadoop.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
>
> parquet.level=WARNING
> parquet.hadoop.level=WARNING
> org.apache.parquet.level=WARNING
> org.apache.parquet.hadoop.level=WARNING
> ```
>
> - Add the file to the job. In Hive, this is most easily done like so:
>
>   ```
>   ADD FILE /path/to/parquet-logging.properties;
>   ```
>
> With this done, when you run your Hive queries, parquet should only
>   log WARNING (and higher) level messages to the stdout container logs.

Answer (score 0):

To turn off all the messages except ERROR, you shoud edit your conf/log4j.properties file changing the following line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

into

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

Hope it could help!

Comment: This actually works for log4j logs from spark, but not for these. These parquet logs seems to be produced by something else? The log4j.rootCategory does not affect them.

Answer (score 0):

not a solution but if you build your own spark then this file: https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetFileReader.java
has most the generations of log messages which you can comment out for now.