# Excessive parquet messages on Spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

After trying *every* approach shown on this question: [How to suppress parquet log messages in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052889/how-to-suppress-parquet-log-messages-in-spark)  ***none*** works with Spark 2.1 -  except the blunt instrument approach of disabling *all* logging below `WARN` level.

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

That is not an acceptable approach (our app writes `INFO` messages for  *reason* .. ).

Note the *first* approach taken was to add

```
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool=ERROR
```

to the `log4j.properties`.  These had *no effect*.  The other approach is also included in my attempts:

```
org.apache.parquet.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
```

with the following added to the jvm options

```
 -Dspark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/parquet.logging.properties"
  -Dspark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/parquet.logging.properties"
```

Likewise no change.

If anyone has found a magic `Quiet down Parquet` button please chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
```

to your log4j.properties file

Comment: Thx.  That had been the first thing attempted (and which did not have any effect). I made that more explicit in the OP.